# Set page title from a child template in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm wanting to set my page titles in the child templates of the layout via jade. I don't want to set them in the routes since that requires a server restart. Here's what I'm hoping to accomplish:

**layout.jade:**

```
!!! 5
  head
    - var title = title || "Default Title Here"
    title #{title}
    // ...
```

**child.jade:**

```
- var title = "Child Title Here"
extends layout
// ...
```

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this would be a great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/654#issuecomment-5859502

layout.jade

```
block variables
!!! 5
head
 - var title = title || "Default Title Here"
 title #{title}
```

child.jade:

```
block variables
  title = "ST"
extends layout
```

Comment: Missing "-" in front of title = "ST on child.jade ?

Comment: Just careful with indentation and make sure to call the variable in the right way: https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

Answer (score 6):

I ended up with a very simple logic since the above answer did not work for me:

in **layout.jade**

```
block head
  - var theTitle = titleVar ? titleVar : "This title was set from The Layout!"
title #{theTitle}
```

in **child.jade:**

```
extends layout
block head
   - var titleVar = "This title was set from the child!"
```

In this solution, the layout will check for the existence of a variable called titleVar: If it does exist (and it's not equal to zero) then layout uses titleVar's value to set as the title, otherwise, the predefined title (in our case: "**This title was set from the Layout!**") from the layout file will take place. Try it for yourself and comment `//` the definition of titleVar from the child template and see the results. 
I hope this solution can help others :)